# UWP MapControl: MapElement fixed heading

Tags: c#, uwp, bing-maps, uwp-maps

I'm adding a MapElement to my MapControl but when I rotate the MapControl, my MapElement rotates along with it. Is it possible to have a fixed heading on the element?

I've tried using a RotateTransform on the MapElement but the Element seems to just completely disappear.

I'm using the following code:
Also, the `<Planes:Airplane />` object is just a custom drawn path.

```
    <Maps:MapControl x:Name="Map" Style="None" Grid.Row="2" TiltInteractionMode="GestureAndControl" ZoomInteractionMode="GestureAndControl" RotateInteractionMode="GestureAndControl" MapServiceToken="TOKEN HERE">
        <!-- Airplane Layer -->
        <Planes:Airplane x:Name="Airplane" Type="Prop" MaxHeight="80" Maps:MapControl.NormalizedAnchorPoint="0.5,0.5" />
    </Maps:MapControl>
```

Comment: If you want the angle of the element to remain the same even when you rotate the parent angle, RotateTransform Angle has to be set to Negative of Rotate transform Angle of Parent Element.

Comment: But when I change the RotateTransform's angle, the plane literally disappears off the map.

Comment: CenterX and CenterY Plays an important Role. Your Plane Disappears because you might be setting CenterX and CenterY to 0. It should be half of the Width and Height of the Plane

Comment: If you are not setting Width and Height at all, Bind the RotateTransform CenterX and CenterY to half of Calculated (Width || Height)/2 so that it rotates at center of plane.

Comment: I am setting both of those, so I'm really unsure why this is happening.

Comment: Here is a simple Grid Inside Grid Example.

<Grid x:Name="grid" Width="200" Height="200" Background="Red">
            <Grid.RenderTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="125" CenterX="100" CenterY="100"/>
            </Grid.RenderTransform>
            <Grid Width="100" Height="100" Background="Blue" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" >
                <Grid.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-125"/>
                </Grid.RenderTransform>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>

If you notice, The Angle is Negative the actual Angle of Parent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm adding a MapElement to my MapControl but when I rotate the MapControl, my MapElement rotates along with it. Is it possible to have a fixed heading on the element?

[MapElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapelement.aspx) doesn't inherit from [UIElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.uielement.aspx), which is the origin of `RenderTransform`. So it is not possible to use RenderTransform on an MapElement.

But as a workaround you can consider using [MapItemsControl](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapitemscontrol.aspx) to put any control or image on the map as you want and you can rotate or translate the image when you rotate the MapControl.

MainPage.Xaml:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Maps:MapControl
        Width="500"
        Height="500"
        x:Name="myMap"            
        ZoomInteractionMode="GestureAndControl"
        TiltInteractionMode="GestureAndControl"   
        MapServiceToken="MapServiceToken">
            <Maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="mapItems">
                <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel>
                            <Image Source="{Binding ImageSourceUri}" 
                                   Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Location}">
                                <Image.RenderTransform>
                                    <TransformGroup>
                                        <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding Rotate.Angle}"
                                                         CenterX="{Binding Rotate.CenterX}"
                                                         CenterY="{Binding Rotate.CenterY}"/>
                                        <TranslateTransform X="{Binding Translate.X}"
                                                            Y="{Binding Translate.Y}"/>
                                    </TransformGroup>
                                </Image.RenderTransform>
                            </Image>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </Maps:MapItemsControl>
        </Maps:MapControl>
        <Button Name="myAdd" Click="myAdd_Click">Click Me to Add Element</Button>
        <Button Name="btnRotate" Click="btnRotate_Click">Click Me to Rotate Element</Button>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
public class InterestPoint
{
    public Uri ImageSourceUri { get; set; }
    public Geopoint Location { get; set; }
    public RotateTransform Rotate{ get; set; }
    public TranslateTransform Translate { get; set; }
    public Point CenterPoint { get; set; }
}
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private List<InterestPoint> InitInterestPoints(BasicGeoposition location)
    {
        List<InterestPoint> points = new List<InterestPoint>();
        points.Add(new InterestPoint {
            ImageSourceUri = new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/mappin.png"),
            Location = new Geopoint(location),
            Rotate=new RotateTransform
            {
                Angle=15,
                CenterX=28.5,
                CenterY=88
            },
            Translate=new TranslateTransform
            {
                X=-28.5,
                Y=-90
            }
        });

        return points;
    }

    private void myAdd_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        mapItems.ItemsSource = InitInterestPoints(myMap.Center.Position);
    }

    private void btnRotate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var points = mapItems.ItemsSource as List<InterestPoint>;
        points[0].Rotate.Angle += 10;
    }
}
```

Here is the Effect:
[image]

And Here is the link to the whole demo: [MapElementRotationSample](https://github.com/elvisxia/MapElementRotationSample).

Notes: The Image is added taking the left up point as anchor point. So you need to translate the image according to the image size.(My image is 57*90, so I need to translate it (-28.5,-88) to let the needle point be the center point).

Comment: The image still rotates as you rotate the map, that part should be an easy fix though. The only problem I'm having with mine is since I'm using a path and not an image, it keeps disappearing when I do anything.

Comment: One problem I'm having is that the icon is showing up in the top left hand corner for some reason, any idea why that would be?

Comment: The icon shows up based on `Maps:MapControl.Location`. So if this location is not the center point of your map. The icon will be shown somewhere else.

Comment: The problem was that the local was originally null, and because of that it would show in the top left hand corner of the screen and never move, even when I changed locations.

Comment: If I could give you a hundred up votes, I would. Thank you for this sample code.

Comment: Suggest Edit: You should obfuscate your MapServiceToken key for security concerns.