# UWP mapcontrol mapicon rotate with map, need to be fixed

Tags: c#, uwp

UWP mapcontrol  mapicon rotate with map, need to be fixed. Does not know how to fix it or any workaround. [unrotated map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsVm9.png) [rotated map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cReiw.png)

Adding icons with code below

```
    private async void Add_cam(Geocoordinate Coordinate,GPoint point,string text,WriteableBitmap wb)
    {
        MapIcon icon = new MapIcon();
        InMemoryRandomAccessStream ras = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
        await wb.RotateFree(point.angle).ToStream(ras, BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId);
        var str = RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(ras);

        icon.Image = str;
        icon.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 0.5);

        icon.Location = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
        {
            Altitude = Coordinate.Point.Position.Altitude,
            Longitude = point.x,
            Latitude = point.y
        });
        icon.Title = text;
        Map.MapElements.Add(icon);
    }
```

Comment: On your Capture Button Create a `RotateTransform` and set the angle to Negative angle of the Actual map Rotation. So that your icon will always stay in correct angle.

Answer (score 1):

There is no method to rotate [MapIcon](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.maps.mapicon.aspx) since it inherits from `MapElement`, not `UIElement`, it doesn't implement the `Transform` function.

So an easy way to solve this case is to replace this `MapIcon` with an `Image` control and rotate this `Image`, to do this, you can refer to this case: [UWP MapControl: MapElement fixed heading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39495611/uwp-mapcontrol-mapelement-fixed-heading/39505140#39505140).